# NullPointerException in designed data structures when adding elements to

Tags: java, data-structures

i have three class Hashmap<K,V> , List, Pair<K,V> :

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myList = new List<>();
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            myList.add("" + i);
            hashMap.add("" + i, "" + i+1000);
        }


    }
}
```

Hashmap:

```
public class HashMap <K,V>{
    private List<Pair<K,V>>[] array;
    private int firstFreeIndex;

    public HashMap(){
        this.array = new List[32];
        this.firstFreeIndex=0;
    }

    // to retrieve a value with key;
    public V get(K key){
        //to do anything with key we need hashValue;
        int hashValue = Math.abs(key.hashCode() % this.array.length);
        if(this.array[hashValue] == null){
            return null;
        }
        List<Pair<K,V>> nList = this.array[hashValue];
        for(int i =0; i< nList.size(); i++){
            if(nList.value(i).getKey().equals(key)){
                return nList.value(i).getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // to add pairs;
    public void add(K key, V value){
        if(key == null){
            return;
        }
        List<Pair<K,V>> nList = getList(key);
        int index = getIndexOf(nList,key);

        if(index < 0){
            nList.add(new Pair<>(key,value));
            this.firstFreeIndex++;
        } else{
            nList.value(index).setValue(value);
        }

        if(1.0*this.firstFreeIndex/this.array.length > 0.75){
            //increasing the size of internal array;
            grow();
        }
    }

    private List<Pair<K,V>> getList(K key){
        //for getting list and everything that should be done with key
        //we need hashValue;
        int hashValue = Math.abs(key.hashCode() % this.array.length);
        if(this.array[hashValue] == null){
            this.array[hashValue] = new List<>();
        }
        return this.array[hashValue];
    }

    private int getIndexOf(List<Pair<K,V>> nList, K key){
        for (int i=0; i<nList.size(); i++){
            if(nList.value(i).getKey().equals(key)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void grow(){
        List<Pair<K,V>>[] nArray = new List[this.array.length*2];

        for(int i=0; i < this.firstFreeIndex; i++){
            copy(nArray,i);
        }

        this.array = nArray;

    }

    private void copy(List<Pair<K,V>>[] nList, int index){
        for(int i = 0; i<this.array[index].size(); i++){
            Pair<K,V> nP = this.array[index].value(i);

            int hashValue = Math.abs(nP.getKey().hashCode() % nList.length);
            if(nList[hashValue] == null){
                nList[hashValue] = new List<>();
            }
            nList[hashValue].add(nP);
        }
    }
}
```

List:

```
public class List <T>{
    private T[] array;
    private int firstFreeIndex;
    public List(){
        this.array = (T[]) new Object[10];
        this.firstFreeIndex = 0;
    }

    public void add(T value){
        if(this.firstFreeIndex == this.array.length){
            grow();
        }
        this.array[this.firstFreeIndex] = value;
        this.firstFreeIndex++;
    }


    public boolean contains(T value){
        for(int i=0; i < this.firstFreeIndex; i++){
            if(this.array[i].equals(value)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void remove(T value){
        int index = indexOfValue(value);
        if(index<0){
            return;
        }
        moveToLeft(index);
        this.firstFreeIndex--;

    }

    private void grow(){
        int newSize = this.array.length + this.array.length /2;
        T[] nArray = (T[]) new Object[newSize];
        for(int i=0; i< this.array.length; i++){
            nArray[i] = this.array[i];
        }

        this.array = nArray;
    }

    public T value(int index){
        if(index < 0 || index >= this.firstFreeIndex){
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("index " + index + " is outside of [0," + this.firstFreeIndex + "]");
        }
        return this.array[index];
    }

    public int size(){
        return this.firstFreeIndex;
    }

    public int indexOfValue(T value){
        for(int i=0; i<this.firstFreeIndex;i++){
            if(this.array[i].equals(value)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void moveToLeft(int index){
        for(int i = index; i<this.firstFreeIndex-1;i++){
            this.array[i] = this.array[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Pair:

```
public class Pair <K,V>{
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Pair(K key, V value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }

    public V getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

when i try to add 100 pair elements to hashmap i get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "List.size()" because "this.array[index]" is null
> at HashMap.copy(HashMap.java:79)
> at HashMap.grow(HashMap.java:71)
> at HashMap.add(HashMap.java:44)
> at Main.main(Main.java:10)

why? i just get this error on intellij , and the same implementations got no error on netbeans.
im new to programming , so there might be something that i dont know

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize the `HashMap`:

```
    public HashMap(){
        this.array = new List[32];
        this.firstFreeIndex=0;
    }
```

You create an array of `List` with 32 null references.

Afterward, when you try to grow the `HashMap`:

```
        for(int i = 0; i<this.array[index].size(); i++){
```

You use the array cells without verifying if they are null references.

I should have read:

```
     if(this.array[index] != null)
     {
        for(int i = 0; i<this.array[index].size(); i++){
```

The bug may not happens on some implementation depending of `hashCode`. If you are lucky, the array can be full before the `grow` invocation. If you are less lucky, their will have some holes.

Comment: Thank you sir. problem solved and i learnt a lot.